# Empty pdf file after sync using dropbox api on android

Tags: android, pdf, dropbox-api

i wrote an android app which exports pdf file over email and dropbox. When i send the pdf file using email intent, i can view the file on my mac.. But the same file uploaded into dropbox via android dropbox api, the pdf file seems to be empty when i open on my mac. But the file size of both dropbox version and email version are the same. This only happens for pdf files, when i send a text file over dropbox android api, it works fine.

Anyone experienced such issue before ? and are there any solutions ? i'm using the latest dropbox android sdk from dropbox developer side.

```
 public DropboxExportManager(Activity context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    private void setUpAccountDetail() {
        handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog
                .setMessage(context.getString(R.string.uploading_message));

        dropBoxAccountManager = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(
                context.getApplicationContext(), PropertyManager.getInstance().getString(
                PropertyKeys.DROP_BOX_KEY), PropertyManager.getInstance().getString(
                PropertyKeys.DROP_BOX_SECRET));
    }

    public void connectToDropbox(String file) {
        setUpAccountDetail();

        this.dropBoxFile = file;

        if (dropBoxAccountManager.hasLinkedAccount()) {
            uploadFileToDropBox();
        } else {
            dropBoxAccountManager.startLink(context, REQUEST_LINK_TO_DROPBOX);

        }

    }

    public void uploadFileToDropBox() {

        try {

            DbxPath dropboxFilePath = new DbxPath(DbxPath.ROOT, directory + dropBoxFile);

            DbxFileSystem dropBoxFileSystem = DbxFileSystem
                    .forAccount(dropBoxAccountManager.getLinkedAccount());

            File localFile = new File(FileService.getInstance()
                    .getPathAndCreateIfNotExists(FileService.EXTERNAL,
                            AppConstants.CACHE_DIRECTORY + dropBoxFile));

            dropBoxFileSystem.addPathListener(pathListener, dropboxFilePath,
                    Mode.PATH_ONLY);

            if (localFile.exists()) {
                Logs.d("Local file exist");
                DbxFile dropboxFile;
                if (!dropBoxFileSystem.exists(dropboxFilePath)) {
                    Logs.e("Dropbox file doesnt exist");
                    dropboxFile = dropBoxFileSystem.create(dropboxFilePath);
                    writeDropBoxFileFromFile(localFile, dropboxFile);
                } else {
                    Logs.d("Dropbox file exist");
                    dropBoxFileSystem.delete(dropboxFilePath);
                    dropboxFile = dropBoxFileSystem.create(dropboxFilePath);
                    writeDropBoxFileFromFile(localFile, dropboxFile);
                }

                if (dropboxFile != null) {
                    dropboxFile.close();
                }

                if (exportManager != null) {
                    exportManager.onExportComplete();
                }

            } else {
                Logs.e("Local file doesnt exist");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            statusMessage = "Dropbox test failed: " + e;
        }

        Logs.d(statusMessage);
    }

    public boolean writeDropBoxFileFromFile(File file, DbxFile dbFile) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    fin));
            String line = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            dbFile.writeString(sb.toString());

            fin.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            dbFile.close();

        }

        return true;

    }

    private DbxFileSystem.PathListener pathListener = new DbxFileSystem.PathListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPathChange(DbxFileSystem dbFS, DbxPath dbPath, Mode arg2) {
            try {

                Logs.d("Uploading File "
                        + dbFS.getSyncStatus().upload.inProgress);

                if (dbFS.getSyncStatus().upload.inProgress) {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            progressDialog.show();
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    dbFS.removePathListenerForAll(pathListener);
                }

            } catch (DbxException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Are you using text file specific API functions?

Comment: @mkl im using file syncing api support based on the example given with the sdk.. Im not aware of any special api based on file type. Are there special API for dropbox based on file type which i missed ?

Comment: @mkl you are right.. i was using a wrong api.. i should have used the core api and not the sync api for pdf or image files.. Thanks mate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to why your code doesn't work, I think your comment above is right in that it relates to trying to read the file as though it's text. (At the very least, you're probably writing a couple newlines into the file.)

But there's really no need for that code anyway. Instead of calling the `writeDropBoxFileFromFile` method you wrote, just do `dropboxFile.writeFromExistingFile(localFile, false);`

(The docs are here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/android#com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxFile. Just look for "`writeFromExistingFile`".)

Answer (score 0):

Finally i figure out the problem. It was so silly of me to jump into programming before read more about the apis. Seems like dropbox has two type of apis. One for normal text writing using the sync pi and another for more complex task like uploading files using the core api.

[Core API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android)

Comment: This is definitely **wrong**. Both APIs work equally well for text files and for non-text files. The Sync API, for example, comes with an ImageGrid sample that shows working with image files. If you're still interested in using the Sync API and want to figure out what's wrong with your code, please share the code so we can try to spot the bug.

Comment: @smarx this is the second time i tried using this api.. i'm dont know much how it works.. i added the code above. but i think now i know where it went wrong.. i think im using the stringer builder when writing to the file... that doesnt work for none-text file.. thanks in advance :)